# Silverlight: Auto scrolling page when tabbing to different textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using silverlight 2.0 with C# for my application.
Few of the pages are quite long and contain quite a few of textboxes. The question I have is:

I use 'tab' to move between the textboxes on the page. When I tab into a TB that is not shown on the page - how can I make it so that the pages autoscroll to display which field I am on the page?

Right now I have to manually scroll the page. I have tried couple of things and would like to know if there is an easier more efficient way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to Version 2.0?

Comment: The project is in development since late 2008. 
The possibility to switching to 3.0 or later is feasible, but having no previous silverlight experience, I am not sure how much work is involved (we are also using telerik controls & wcf services).
Have you ever migrated to the newer version of SL? what was your experience like? I saw some tutorials online briefly but never followed through with it due to the time limitation.
But if it is something we could do within reasonable time, we would be interested.
Also, issue mentioned above will still be an issue!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a behavior that looks good for the "scroll into view" issue. I haven't tried it myself though, so I cannot vouch for the quality (and I don't know if it works in Silverlight 2):
[Silverlight BringIntoView() extension method (with OnGotFocus behavior)](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotjosh/archive/2009/11/05/bringintoview-extension-method-for-silverlight-with-behavior.aspx)

And I very much recommend migrating to Silverlight 3 (and later this year, 4) if you are planning on doing more work on the application. It is hard to say how difficult it will be for you, especially since you are new to Silverlight. That depends on the nature of your application. I can only say that when we migrated from 2 to 3 it was not that difficult, and we have a big application with a lot of strange hacks. I was expecting a world of pain, but it was done in a couple of days. Oh, and you can get the Telerik components for version 3 as well. 
I would suggest that you try compiling the app in Silverlight 3 with the upgraded Telerik components and see how many build errors you get. Then you will probably have a pretty clear indication of whether it's worth it or not.

Comment: It will not work in SL2.0 because Behaviors got introduced in version 3.0. Thanks for the info though (3.0 starting to look very appealing now :) )